# How can I add a specific date format in ASP.NET MVC layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add code in _Layout.cshtml to implement display of Date such as

**Tuesday, August 11, 2015**

any possible to add a controller for layout view? or maybe use javascript in layout file?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this logic top of layout page

```
@{
    var date = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
}
```

And now you can use date variable anywhere inside layout.

```
<div class="datetime">@date</div>
```